# R: crosstable anaysis for NPS calculation in r

Tags: r

i I have a nps survey data in R, the survey raw data look like this:

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "Gender  Age  Promoters   Passives   Detractors
F       20   0           1          0
M       19   1           0          0
M       21   1           0          0
F       19   0           0          1
M       20   1           0          0
M       18   0           1          0
F       18   1           0          0
F       21   0           0          1
M       19   0           0          1
F       20   0           1          0
F       21   0           0          1   ",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Generally nps is calculated as:

> (Number of Promoters)/all responses - (Number of Detractors)/all
>   responses)

(0 means no response of course)

Now i would like to calculate nps for for specific age, gender and many other variables... like crosstable. 
The desire outcome would look like this:

```
        gender   age
        ------   ------------------
total   F    M   18   19   20   21

0      -0.6   0.7   0.1   -0.1  0.3   -0.2
```

actually i tried group by

```
df %>% 
group_by(Gender) %>% 
summarise(nps = (sum(Promoters)-sum(Detractors))/(sum(Promoters)+sum(Passives)+sum(Detractors)))
```

but it comes out like this:

```
     age    nps
     0      0
     1      0
     2      0
     3      0
```

I'm not sure how to do this in R. Any help would be great!

Comment: I'm not getting the same results from the code that you are getting, but I'm guessing if you just do a second summary by the other grouping variable (Age/Gender) you will get your desired output

Comment: I don't understand if you are trying to calculate `nps` separately for all females, all males, all 18yr olds, all 19yr olds, etc... or if you are crossing age and gender, to calculate `nps` for "female 18yr olds" and "male 18yr olds", etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the NPS, broken down by gender like this:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df_gender <- df %>%
          group_by(Gender) %>%
          summarise(nps = (sum(Promoters)/n()) - (sum(Detractors/n())))
```

And the NPS, broken down by age like this:

```
 df_age <- df %>%
          group_by(Age) %>%
          summarise(nps = (sum(Promoters)/n()) - (sum(Detractors/n())))
```

If you want the NPS broken down by age and gender simultaneously, then just add both column names to the group_by statement.